# Insert a logo in upper right corner of R markdown pdf document

Tags: r, pdf, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

I am getting started with R markdown and I would like to create a new report having our company image `logo.png` in the upper right corner of each page.

Is there a way to code this in the YAML section or need this to be done in a R chunk section?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution:

```
---
title:
header-includes: 
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   \pagestyle{fancy}
   \setlength\headheight{28pt}
   \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{GPIM_Logo_300x85.png}}
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{GPIM}
output: pdf_document
---
```

Comment: this looks really nice, but it doesn't add the image to the first page for me; anyone know how to force that?

Comment: `header-includes: 
      \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      \usepackage{graphicx}
      \usepackage{eurosym}
  \usepackage{booktabs,xcolor}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm}
  \rhead{MainSky Stress Test Report - \today}
  \lhead{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{path & logo}}
  \rfoot{Page \thepage}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
output: pdf_document`

Comment: @Daniel_D, I added logo with this method successfully. But today I failed adding logo to the same pdf file I generated previously. Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Daniel_D this is veryhelpful. How would you center the logo?

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `includes` option in the yaml to specify a custom addition to your latex header. The yaml part would look like

```
---
output: 
    pdf_document:
      keep_tex: true
      includes:
          in_header: header.tex
---
```

and you need to save a separate file called `header.tex` with the following defining your company logo like so:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width = .05\textwidth]{logo.png}}
```

Here I used the `fancyhdr` latex package to add the logo, but there are other potential solutions. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/add-logo-on-each-page) for more options.

Comment: Where do I need to save the header.tex file? In the same directory where my rmd. report is saved?

Comment: Suppose the path where my logo is stored under: Y:\Risikomanagement\Stress Tests. How should your header.tex code look like?

Comment: I think you can give it the full path to the logo: `\rhead{\includegraphics[width = .05\textwidth]{Y:\Risikomanagement\Stress Tests\logo.png}}`

Comment: I'd recommend you not to use the full path, especially under Windows. Put everything in the same directory, and always use relative paths everywhere.

Answer (score 25):

I've tried many solutions presented here and in other forums, none of which worked. I've finally came to a solution that worked for me.

```
---
title: 'Fancy Title Here'
author: "Diego"
date: "today"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
---
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} % make more space for the header
\pagestyle{fancyplain} % use fancy for all pages except chapter start
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{C:/Path/to/logo/logo}} % right logo
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule below header
```

I hope that helps someone the same way it helped me.

Comment: Tried this and the logo appears but it appears on each page. I need it only on the first page

Comment: @Diego, this really helps me a lot, thank you very much. I've been stuck in the logo issue for several days after my previous logo solution became invalid, which I still have no idea why. And finally with your solution I got the logo back!

Comment: @Diego: This is really nice solution, but how can I refer to the image with a relative instead of full path? Say I have the image stored in a folder `figs` located in the same folder where the `.Rmd` file is stored. How can I refer to it without adding the full path to the image file in `\includegraphics`?

Answer (score 2):

For those using `flexdashboard`see this addition to entry preamble text for **logos and favicon**, although its upper left not right:

http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#logo__favicon

so your start of the `.Rmd` file looks like this:

```
---
title: "myappR"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    logo: mylogo.png
    favicon: mylogo.png
    theme: bootstrap
runtime: shiny
---
```

I left my logo in the root directory with a simple name. And:

- Kept logo height 48 pixels as this plays nicely with the theme,
- Be careful of spaces and indents and,
- Do not forget the ending **:** after flexdashboard.

Comment: How do you adjust the size of this logo? I have one placed using this method, but it's very big and it isn't displaying very well :(

Comment: I used a graphics package and resized the image to be 48 pixels high. Take care when scaling so the width also changes proportionately. I used irfanview but you might have others available.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to make a logo only on the first page:

```
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} % make more space for the header
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} % this is to remove the default plain style for the first page
\thispagestyle{fancy} % use fancy for all pages except chapter start
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width = 100pt]{ManchesterLogo.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove rule below header
```