# get rid of captions when using texreg in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, texreg

How do you suppress captions for a texreg table? I'm using Rmarkdown to generate a LaTeX file. Here's a simple example:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(texreg)
data <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4), b=c(6,3,4,4))
texreg(lm(a~b, data=data), caption="", custom.note="", float.pos="h!")
```
````

The table I get has a caption on the bottom that says "Table 1:". How do I get rid of it? Thanks.

Comment: Adding a table=FALSE option to texreg gets rid of the caption but then how do I restore the table's centering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the YAML section where LaTeX packages can be included, add the caption package:

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{caption}
```

Then at the beginning of the RMarkdown document body add:

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
```

This removes the caption labels for all tables.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have an external .tex file for additional formatting (i. e. I made a file for including a logo in the header of each page as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document)) you should include `\usepackage{caption}` (just this line) in the external .tex file, not in the yaml header of the RMarkdown document.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `table=FALSE`, which would produce a tabular not embedded in a table, and hence contain no caption.