# Don't include chunk name in table name in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, chunks, kableextra, tableheader

I have a problem with Rmarkdown and writing tables to html. I'm writing tables with kableextra and the table name comes out like this in the html output: (#tab:*chunk name*)*table name*. I only want my own table name I give to kable via caption= without the (#tab:*chunk name*).

I've already tried the suggestion from
[How to suppress automatic table name and number in an .Rmd file using xtable or knitr::kable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182147/how-to-suppress-automatic-table-name-and-number-in-an-rmd-file-using-xtable-or) :

```
header-includes:
    - \usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

But it doesn't seem to work for html_document2, only for html_document. I'm using bookdown::html_document2 as output, because it is needed for some other things in the document, so I can't switch to html_document.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're more likely to receive help if in addition to describing the key components of your yaml section, you provide a reproducible example with the yalm section and table code.

Comment: it looks like you are using Latex syntax, but I thought we couldn't use latex syntax when creating HTML documents, only PDF docs. If you look at your resource link, they are using `output: pdf_document`, and you are using `bookdown::html_document2`