# knitr/Rmarkdown image before title

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to add an image to the title page of a PDF document rendered using RStudio with knitr. How can I include an image on the first page above the title?

I'm trying to use `- \includegraphics{logo.png}` which works, but then I cannot include subtitle text. I also cannot include this under `title:`

```
subtitle:
- \includegraphics{logo.png}
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
```

Comment: See the accepted answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document) question and it may lead you in the direction of what you are looking for.