# Insert a logo in upper right corner of Rmarkdown pdf document & header

Tags: r, image, pdf, markdown, rstudio

I viewed the ["insert a logo in upper right corner of R markdown pdf document"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document)topic and I managed to insert a logo in the upper right corner using this input:

```
  pdf_document:
      keep_tex: true
      includes:
        in_header: header.tex
```

But  when I additionally include `author:` `title:` `date:` the logo disappears. 
I realised, that in a document with more than one page, the logo appears from the second page onwards but not on the first page, where I included the header

How can I include the logo on the first page additional to the normal infomations as author:, titel: and so on?

Comment: can you add a link to the topic you viewed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document Don't know if I can refer to this articel in an other way, but should find it with that link. I now tried it with a documnet with more than one page. the logo appears from the second page onwards but not on the first page, where I included the header.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in 'header.tex'

```
\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{%
\begin{center}
\LARGE
\hfill \includegraphics[width=4cm,height=6cm]{logo.png}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}
```