# 2 Logo in R Markdown on PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using below code to add a company logo in r markdown in a pdf version and
the output is fine.
I need to add 2 logo's on each page - one for my client and other for our
company. 
Is is possible to add 2 logo's in a pdf using r markdown.

```
    ---
title: "Complaints Text Model"
author: "ANALYTICS TEAM"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes 
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
always_allow_html: yes
---
\addtolength{\headheight}{1.0cm} 
\pagestyle{fancyplain} 
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{D:/D Drive Data/Shivi/R Project/my company.png}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

One can be on one side of the page and other logo on the other side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a logo in upper right corner of R markdown pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is imitate your syntax for the left header:

```
\rhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{D:/D Drive Data/Shivi/R Project/my company.png}}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=1.2cm]{D:/D Drive Data/Shivi/R Project/client.png}}
```