# Include logo (image) on every page of R markdown pdf

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I am trying to include my company logo in an R markdown report. The output has to be pdf. The logo has to be used as a template on every page of the report in the top left of the file. Just for example, you can use this google logo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google#/media/File:Google_2015_logo.svg

I want the report to look like this (sorry for the blurry image but I just wanted to give an example) -

[image]

The google logo on top left should be present on every page.

I have done searches but all the searches that I have done are showing how to do this using latex or HTML output.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-logo.html

[Insert a logo in upper right corner of R markdown pdf document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document)

[2 Logo in R Markdown on PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704598/2-logo-in-r-markdown-on-pdf)

[add image in title page of rmarkdown pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389149/add-image-in-title-page-of-rmarkdown-pdf)

The closest I have came is with this markdown document that is called `reports.Rmd` which looks like -

````
---
title: "Report"
output: pdf_document
params: 
  study: NA
  mid : NA
---

![Caption.](google.png)

```{r, echo=FALSE}
paste0("Study : ", params$study)
paste0("ID",  params$mid)
```
````

and I run this from another R script as -

```
library(rmarkdown)
study <- 'ABC'
mid <- '73023'

rmarkdown::render('reports.Rmd', pdf_document(), params = list(
  study = study, mid = mid
))
```

This runs and produce this output

[image]

I'll be able to resize the image with [How to set size for local image using knitr for markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625990/how-to-set-size-for-local-image-using-knitr-for-markdown/)  but I don't know how to place this on top left of the page. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you not want to use latex or html solutions?

Comment: This company report has to be a PDF document, I cannot share HTML files. As far as latex is concerned I haven't used it before and don't know what changes I need to do in my markdown file.

Comment: Bro, you really should use LaTeX solution with the case of PDF-document. I prepared to you a template. Wait a moment.

Comment: If i helped to you, can you accept my answer (put a tick). Big thx ;)

Comment: You can create an HTML document from Rmarkdown, and then *Print* the file to PDF from the web browser to retain HTML elements when created, and then send the PDF to whoever, it's a simple trick to keep in mind for future projects

Comment: @DanielJachetta Yes, you are right. And we can to make it more easier: ```"Knit to Html" - > "Open in Browser" -> right click + "Save as PDF..."``` But TeX-style will be lost. All depends on the requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a template for you:

````
---
title: 'You are really need to use LaTeX'
author: "You"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  pdf_document

header-includes:
     \usepackage{fancyhdr}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\addtolength{\headheight}{3.0cm} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width = 100pt]{your_pic.png}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 


This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for 
authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown 
see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

and blah-blah...
````

[image]

So, don't forget to install `LaTeX` and packages `fancyhdr, graphics`.

How to do it, you can see [there.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex.html)
Or you can install MikTeX etc. You can find a lot of info at the SO/in the web.

*The knowledge of LaTeX will save you not once a time in the future life ;)*

Comment: Also, if the OP is unaccustomed to LaTeX commands, there's LyX which uses LaTeX. Check that out: [LyX](https://www.lyx.org/)...

Comment: Hi @manro, do you have any idea how to rotate a page ? I have asked a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693683/rotate-table-pdf-output-from-markdown

Comment: @user16024709 I'll try to find a solution ;)