# Rotate table pdf output from Markdown

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I want to rotate table output by 90 degrees on pdf. I am using markdown to generate a report and `kable` to display the tables in a loop. If possible, I would like to continue using `kable` since there are lot of other things which are dependent on it that I haven't included in this MWE.

This is a simple example using `iris` dataset. I tried using `landscape` function from this post [Rotate a table from R markdown in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840878/rotate-a-table-from-r-markdown-in-pdf)

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage{lscape}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  

Report page - 

```{r results='asis'}  
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
for (i in 1:3) {
  print(landscape(kable_styling(
    kable(iris[i:(i+5), ], format = "latex", align = "c", booktabs = TRUE, 
   longtable = TRUE, row.names = FALSE), latex_options = c("striped"), full_width = T)))
}
```
````

But this only rotates the page number keeping the table as it is.

[image]

I am actually looking for a solution which provides me the output in this way -

[image]

To clarify, all the pages with table data in it (3 for this example) should be rotated whereas rest of them should remain as it is. Also, I need `longtable = TRUE` in `kable` since in my actual example I am printing lot of rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate a table from R markdown in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840878/rotate-a-table-from-r-markdown-in-pdf)

Comment: @lcgodoy Not really. That is the same link which I shared in my post and I showed that it is not what I want. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you taken a look [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47136674/9220758)? You need to add some `latex` code into the Rmd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use package `rotating`

I added a simple example for you.

````
---
title: "test"
header-includes: \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
#or \usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

    ```{r setup, include = FALSE}
    library(flextable)
    ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
    ```

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
    `r ft`
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
    ```
````

[image]

Further you can modify it for your tasks ;)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer @manro. In my case the issue is that I am printing long tables (around 1000 rows) which prints for multiple pages. When I use this solution I get error `! Dimension too large.`.

Comment: @user16024709 I think, that you should split your long tables to small

Comment: @user16024709 Also, try to ask there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/ 
An answer is interesting for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I found another way using rotatebox.

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  \usepackage{lscape}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```  

Report page - 


```{r results='asis', warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}  
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
for (i in 1:3) {
  cat('\\rotatebox{90}{')
  print(kable(iris[i:(i+5), ], format = "latex", align = "c", booktabs = TRUE,
          row.names = FALSE))
  cat('}')
  cat("\n\\newpage\n")
}
```
````

Comment: Nice, I'll try your solution.