# Company logo in PDF output only on the first page

Tags: r, r-markdown

I was wondering if there is a way to include the company logo to a PDF document created by R Markdown **only on the first page of the document**. I have searched for an answer and the closest I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982052/insert-a-logo-in-upper-right-corner-of-r-markdown-pdf-document). There are multiple solutions presented in the answers, however, neither of them works for me because they either:

- include the logo at every page of the document (not just first); or
- include the chapter title in the header (and a horizontal line below it) along with the logo.

I am looking for a way to include **just the plain logo**, with **no chapter titles** only on the **first page** of a PDF R Markdown document and I've ran out of all the resources I could find online. Is there someone who could aid me?

Before anyone asks: yes, it strictly has to be a PDF document, not HTML.

Comment: I do it by using : ``\includegraphics[width=7cm]{yourCOMPANYlogo.jpg}`` You can adjust the width value. To use this you have to use R Markdown and Latex tho.

Comment: Is this something I would put in the YAML, or below where the regular text is?

Comment: I will post you a more complete example as an answer since I can't post long code in comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\includegraphics` code line is insert after the **R SETUP** chunk in markdown.
Here is an example of where I put the line `\includegraphics` :

````
---
geometry: "margin=1.5cm"
classoption: landscape
output:
  pdf_document: # Export to pdf
    number_sections: yes 
includes:
          in_header: ltx.sty
---



```{r SETUP, include=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,  
                  warning = FALSE,  
                  message = FALSE,  
                  results = "asis")

library(knitr) 
library(kableExtra) 
library(some_packages)

options(scipen = 999,
    digits = 2,
    width = 110)

```

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{87,146,204}
\allsectionsfont{\color{astral}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


<!-- Title page -->
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{logo.jpg}

\begin{center}\begin{Large}
Project 1
\end{Large}\end{center}

\vfill


# Some R chunk
```{r results='asis'}
# Table, code, graphics.
```
````

So the line is insert between the R SETUP chunk and the next R chunk.

Comment: On a second note, though, if my Markdown doc includes the title, author and date of the document, is there a way to have the logo appear in the header above the title and other fields?

Comment: I am quite not sure how I would do it but I will take a look. If I find something I'm gonna tag you here @J.Doe and update my answer.